# Compiler error: <identifier> expected. How do I resolve this?

Tags: java

I'm getting numerous errors on this assignment. I've done as much of it as I can and seem to have everything in order, yet JGrasp is telling me that there are 49 errors. I'm getting errors on lines 30,31, 33, 36, 37, 40, 41, 42, 43, 47, 48, 54, 55, 56, and 57. I've done everything right, according to my textbook. How do I fix this?

I've added "here" comments after every line that's giving me trouble.

Full Program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageRainfall { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double monthRain = 0;          // Rain for a month
        double totalRain = 0;          // Rainfall accumulator
        double average = 0;            // Average rainfall
        // Keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Number of years.
        System.out.print("Enter the number of years: ");
        int years = 0; // Number of years
        years = keyboard.nextInt();
        // Checks input.
        while (years < 1) {
            System.out.print("Invalid. Enter 1 or greater: ");
            input anotheryears = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    }

    final int NUM_MONTHS = 12; // Months per year

    System.out.println("Enter the rainfall, in inches, for each month."); //here           
    for (int y = 1; y <= years; y++); //here
       {
         for (int m = 1; m <= NUM_MONTHS; m++); //here
         {
            // Gets rainfall for each month.
            System.out.print("Year " + y + " month " + m + ": "); //here
            monthRain = keyboard.nextDouble(); //here

            // Checks input.
            while (monthRain < 0) //here
            { //here
             System.out.print("Invalid. Enter 0 or greater: "); //here
             monthRain = keyboard.nextDouble(); //here
            }

            // Accumulates rainfall.
            totalRain += monthRain; //here
         } //here
      }
      // Calculates average rainfall.
      average = totalRain / (years * NUM_MONTHS);
      // Displays statistics.
      System.out.println("\nNumber of months: " + (years * NUM_MONTHS)); //here
      System.out.println("Total rainfall: " + totalRain + " inches"); //here
      System.out.println("Average monthly rainfall: " + average + " inches"); //here
}
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon after the for-loop declaration.

Comment: `input anotheryears = keyboard.nextInt();` looks weird. Should be `int` I guess.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what the errors are.  Or, better still, read the error messages and figure out what's wrong yourself.  The messages actually say something, if you bother to read them.

Comment: @Thilo: Yeah, it should. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Indent the code**. There main problem is here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double monthRain = 0; 
    //more code...
    while (years < 1) {
        System.out.print("Invalid. Enter 1 or greater: ");
        input anotheryears = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
} //<--- here
//you're closing the main method
//and then you have more code outside of it
final int NUM_MONTHS = 12; // Months per year

System.out.println("Enter the rainfall, in inches, for each month."); //here           
for (int y = 1; y <= years; y++); //here
    //rest of code
```

Apart of this, remove the semicolons after `for` statements:

```
for (int y = 1; y <= years; y++); //<-- remove this
```

It should be like this:

```
for (int y = 1; y <= years; y++) {
    //rest of code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have closed your main block and so the years variable is out-of-scope for the statements that are oddly without a method block.

I think you have an extra curly brace somewhere, or are missing one.